# SQL Inner join not allowed in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the following query I am trying to create 2 inner join for rs1 and rs2 
however in sql server i have only the possibility to select rr1.ResourceId=rs2.Id
but i cannot make rr1.ResourceId=rs1.Id

can you explain me what i should do ?

```
select r.OwningTerritoryId ,rs1.ISRC , rs2.ISRC 
from Resource rs1 , Resource rs2
    inner join ReleaseResource rr1 
       on rr1.ResourceId=rs2.Id
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should be `INNER JOIN`ing the two Resource tables not using a comma.

Comment: You shouldn't mix old style joins (`,`) with ANSI-standard joins (`CROSS JOIN`, `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`) etc in your `FROM` clause. We might be able to help if you could explain how rows from `rs1` and `rs2` are meant to be related - are you really aiming for a cartesian product?

Comment: @bendataclear is right - you don't join them in anyway later on in the query either. If you don't make it a join with explicit criteria it's very hard to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cerate as many inner joins as you want ...

```
select r.OwningTerritoryId ,rs1.ISRC , rs2.ISRC 
from Resource rs1
    inner join ReleaseResource rr2 
       on rr2.ResourceId=rs1.Id
    inner join ReleaseResource rr2
       on rr3.ResourceId=rs1.Id
    inner join ReleaseResource rr3
       on rr4.ResourceId=rs1.Id
    inner join ReleaseResource rr4
       on rr5.ResourceId=rs1.Id
```

Although, [generally], you do this for a reason that requires that a different join condition for each join.

If you want the joins to be between each table in a pair, then between the pairs, then try:

```
select r.OwningTerritoryId ,rs1.ISRC , rs2.ISRC 
   from (Resource r1 join ReleaseResource rr1 
               On rr1.ResourceId = r1.Id)
      join (Resource r2 join ReleaseResource rr2 
               On rr2.ResourceId = r2.Id)
         On r2.id = r1.id   -- Here put condition for this join between the pairs
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this....

```
select r.OwningTerritoryId ,rs1.ISRC , rs2.ISRC from Resource rs1 
inner join ReleaseResource rr1 on rr1.ResourceId=rs2.Id
```

Comment: In this example, where does rr1.ResourceId come from? I don't see a table or alias by that identifier?